# Add data to a plist without deleting the previous data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, plist

As you can see from the title I basically want to update a plist. Actually the app user will type his data in data fields and I will take them and save them in a plist. He can add as many objects as he likes.
I have tried a huge number of different codes for that staff and none of them works. First of all take a look at my plist (I am presenting you the xml code so you can understand it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>TEST</string>
            <key>code</key>
            <string>TEST</string>
            <key>longitude</key>
            <integer>22</integer>
            <key>latitude</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
         </dict>
    </array>
</plist>
```

That was just a simple entry. Now here is the lates code I have used but I had no luck at all

```
NSMutableDictionary *newBuilding = [NSMutableDictionary alloc];
    [newBuilding setValue:@"Test1" forKey:@"name"];
    [newBuilding setValue:@"Test2" forKey:@"code"];
    [newBuilding setValue:@"10" forKey:@"latitude"];
    [newBuilding setValue:@"20" forKey:@"longitude"];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BuildingsInfo.plist"];

    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    if (nil == newArray) {
        newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    }

     [newArray addObject:newBuilding];
 [newArray writeToFile:plistPath atomically: YES];

 }
```

Can anybody spot any mistake? I have written it a lot of times, I have checked every token but I have found no mistakes. I cannot understand why I does not want to work!

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: I have just read that the plist have to be in the documents directory in order for me to be able to write on it. Can anybody let me know how I can transfer the plist to the documents directory once the program is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, you never initialized `newBuilding`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that newArray is returning nil when you are trying to load it from the file, which means on of a few things.

- A) Bad path (try logging it to confirm)
- B) File is poorly formatted
- C) For what ever reason, arrayWithContentsOfFile is not creating a
  mutable array as it ought to
- D) Possibly running out of memory

I ordered these in likeliness of it being the real problem.

On a side note, why not use the convenience constructor `[NSMutableArray array]`, it does the same as your allocation code.

Also a simple `NSLog(@"%@", newArray)` and you will get the array nicely printed to the console for easy visual debugging :)

Comment: Is there any chance that the problem is that I did not transfer the plist in the documents folder?

Comment: Yea, that's what option A is, bad path meaning that the path you are providing is invalid. Also, good catch David, newBuilding never got a call to it's init method.